# Location taxonomy

Tags: location

I want to add a location to my `products/articles` in 2 different ways :

> -user enters a town (linked to a taxonomy) -> I know how to do it
>
> -user enters a county which is automaticly linked to a state (with taxonomy too) -> I don't know which module do that

In this way,

all users could find all products in a city, in a county or in a state.

The other difficulty is that I want a module which "knows" all country and regions of several countries (actually all European countries).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how to help you with your approach, but alternatively you could use the [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module:

> The Location module allows real-world geographic locations to be
>   associated with Drupal nodes, including people, places, and other
>   content.

The module [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) can be combined with it:

> The GMap module provides an interface to the Google Maps API within
>   Drupal. It integrates with the Location module to provide users a
>   clickable map for entering latitude and longitude, as well as to
>   display maps of Drupal nodes and users.

Location allows to add a location field to your content with several capabilities which may cover your requirements.

There are also other similar modules such as [Geolocation](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation).